# I get this error at mid of test case when I use WebdriverManager with selenium in parallel. 'disconnected: not connected to DevTools'

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, webdriver-manager, webdrivermanager-java

```
disconnected: not connected to DevTools
  (Session info: chrome=87.0.4280.88)
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
System info: host: 'C02YM263JHD2', ip: 'fe80:0:0:0:14d0:b87a:ad38:1e24%en0', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.16', java.version: '11.0.8'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: true, browserName: chrome, browserVersion: 87.0.4280.88, chrome: {chromedriverVersion: 87.0.4280.88 (89e2380a3e36c..., userDataDir: /var/folders/pl/yttsdh650jz...}, goog:chromeOptions: {debuggerAddress: localhost:50055}, javascriptEnabled: true, networkConnectionEnabled: false, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: MAC, platformName: MAC, proxy: Proxy(), setWindowRect: true, strictFileInteractability: false, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}, unhandledPromptBehavior: dismiss and notify, webauthn:virtualAuthenticators: true}
Session ID: 13a5db82b5b94c7a17fa75b28040b97e
```